# Force line break location

Tags: ios, swift, string, line-breaks

In my app, I'm displaying user informations with the label on the left, and the value on the right.

As the text is too long, I'm also using multi-line label to display the entire `String`.

At the moment this is my display :

[image]

As you can see the text breaks somewhere not really appropriate.

I would prefer to have :
[image]

Of course, I can insert `\n` in my string just before the `@` sign, but if the email is `john@doe.com` it would takes 2 lines for nothing.

I was looking for a special character like the `nonBreakableSpace` that I could insert in my string *if and only if* it has to be truncated. (I don't want to calculate the number of required line myself to insert the line break manually).

Does anyone knows if it's possible ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as such, but a possible solution for you UI would be to insert an invisible space just before the `@`, and it should break more fitting your needs?

Comment: @Larme TY. The `invisible space` is an unicode char ?

Comment: @Larme TY. You were right `\u{200B}` is the zero-width space. Combined with `lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping` makes it work. Ty!